# I have SSL on Godaddy and website hosted on Azure VM. How to install SSL on Azure VM?

Tags: azure, ssl, virtual-machine, devops

I have PHP website on Godaddy. Now I have moved my Website to Azure VM. I am facing 2 issues.

1. I have SSL on Godaddy then how I can install that SSL on my Azure VM?
2. I can't send emails from my website after uploading the website on Azure VM. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I have SSL on Godaddy and website hosted on Azure VM. How to install SSL on Azure VM?

To install your `SSL certificate` on your Azure VM, you can follow these steps:

1. Export the SSL certificate from external account (`Go Daddy`).
2. Copy the `.pfx` file to your Azure VM.
3. Install the SSL certificate on `VM` by following below steps.

Open run and type `mmc.exe`  in the `Run > click File > Add/Remove Snap-in > Add or Remove Snap-ins dialog box, select Certificates and click Add >Select Computer account and click Next > Select Local computer and click Finish.`

Click OK to close the Add or Remove Snap-ins dialog box.

In the MMC, expand Certificates> Personal > Right-click the personal folder and select All Tasks > Import > click Next > Browse to the .pfx file that you copied to your Azure VM and click Next >Select the option to "Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate" and click Next > Click Finish.

After importing the certificate, you need to assign it to the appropriate bindings in your web server.

Once complete the above steps you can verify that the `SSL` certificate has been installed.

[image]

> I can't send emails from my website after uploading the website on Azure VM. How to fix this issue?

To fix the issue with sending emails from your website on `VM`, you will need to configure an `SMTP` server to handle the email sending by following below steps.

1. Install an SMTP server on VM and configure the SMTP server to allow relaying from your website's IP address.
2. Update your website's email settings to use the SMTP server on VM.
3. Test sending an email from your website to verify that the SMTP server is working correctly.

**Reference**: [How to Install an SSL Certificate on Azure](https://www.ssldragon.com/how-to/install-ssl-certificate/azure/)